# Jquery disable form and enabled

Tags: jquery, attr

I try with this function enable and disabled when send form but  no works , here i put the function :

```
jQuery("#c_input_submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
jQuery("#c_response").empty().append('Error');
jQuery("#c_response")
   .css({"color":"#ffffff","background":"red"})
   .show(2000)
   .delay(2500)
   .hide(2000)
   .delay(1000)
   .function(function() {
       jQuery("#c_input_submit").removeAttr('disabled');
   });
```

When i send the form i get disable the submit button but when end form no re enabled the button other time , i don´t know what it´s bad in the script

By this i put this question for get some help about this , thank´s and regards

Comment: Could you post you full example on jsfiddle? It is unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: When i send a form this code disable submit button , but when go to the end of function must re enabled the same button , the only problem it´s for re enabled the sumit button , regards

Answer (score 0):

With delay function you can use a callback to enable button

```
    jQuery("#c_input_submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    jQuery("#c_response").empty().append('Error');
    jQuery("#c_response")
        .css({
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "background": "red"
    })
        .show(2000)
        .delay(2500)
        .hide(2000)
        .delay(1000,function () {
            jQuery("#c_input_submit").removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/zhgb5ov0/1/)